# Getting directory path from QgsFileWidget using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I use Plugin Builder and Qt Designer to create a plugin on QGIS.

I would like to export a PDF file with results of processing. I try to use `QgsFileWidget`, to get the directory, but I cannot connect the `plugin_dialog_base.ui` file on `plugin.py`, to take the user directory to the `'OUTPUT':` line for export the PDF file.

How do I connect `QgFileWiget` in the interface?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plugin Builder adds a method named `run` to the `plugin.py`. You can implement the script below with a little editing. I assume you have set `storageMode` to `QgsFileWidget.StorageMode.GetDirectory` for `QgsFileWidget` and named `localsave` in  Qt Designer.

```
def run(self):

    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = testDialog() # Change into your dialog name
        
    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()

    if result:
       
        folder_path = self.dlg.localsave.filePath()  # Get folder path from QgsFileWidget
        
        DATANAME = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%y")
        full_path = os.path.join(folder_path, DATANAME + '.pdf' )
        
        print(full_path)
```

Now, you can use `full_path` in `processing.run`.

[image]

Comment: I recive this mensage error >>> AttributeError: 'QgsFileWidget' object has no attribute 'filepath' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Avell/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\polo\POLO.py", line 673, in run
    folder_path = self.dlg.localsave.filepath()
AttributeError: 'QgsFileWidget' object has no attribute 'filepath'

Comment: @NewtonMonteiro Python is a case-sensistive language. Use `filePath`  (Capital P) instead of `filepath`.

Comment: thanks a lot, problem finally solved, I search for this anser a few months!! tks tks tks!!!!

Comment: one more question, I would like the code run only after answer the local to save PDF file and click on OK button, but the code runs anyway click on cancel button or close the window, how fix that

Comment: @NewtonMonteiro It is difficult for me to say anything without seeing your actual code. You can [ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that in a separate post including a sample script.

Answer (score 1):

Use **os.path.join(folder,file)** instead of concatenation. You have no path separator